# How to split document array into multiple arrays by grouping them?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to create a kind of chat. All messages are stored in a "messages" collections and look like this:

```
[
    {
        content: 'content 1',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T19:57:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 2',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T19:58:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 3',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T19:59:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 4',
        userId: '345',
        targetUserId: '123',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T20:00:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 5',
        userId: '345',
        targetUserId: '123',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T20:01:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 6',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T20:02:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 7',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T20:03:42.124Z")
    }
]
```

I need to group this content by userId and timestamp: Of course the messages should be sorted by timestamp. So far this is no big deal. But I also need to group the messages by userId. In this example the user `123` posted three messages - which will be displayed on the left side. The user `345` then answered with two messages - which will be displayed on the right side. And finally the first user again posted two messages.

```
[
    {
        content: 'content 1',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T19:57:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 2',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T19:58:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 3',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T19:59:42.124Z")
    }
], [
    {
        content: 'content 4',
        userId: '345',
        targetUserId: '123',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T20:00:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 5',
        userId: '345',
        targetUserId: '123',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T20:01:42.124Z")
    }
    ], [
    {
        content: 'content 6',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T20:02:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 7',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T20:03:42.124Z")
    }
]
```

I do get the relevant documents by doing

```
Messages.find().sort({ timestamp : 1 })
```

But I don't get it how to create the multiple arrays for each messages "block"

Comment: if this is a matter of `which will be displayed on the left side` why would you then process your collection and convert it into 2 when all you can do is have one user id having a CSS class and the other user id another and do the whole thing in CSS?

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica I understand you. I just tried to keep the example simple. It is not only a matter of css. I need to get the content splitted / grouped. And it seems to be a hard thing (to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for that.

```js
// this is because ISODate would otherwise be undefined and I don't
// want to change your input array
const ISODate = () => {}

const input = [
    {
        content: 'content 1',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T19:57:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 2',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T19:58:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 3',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T19:59:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 4',
        userId: '345',
        targetUserId: '123',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T20:00:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 5',
        userId: '345',
        targetUserId: '123',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T20:01:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 6',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T20:02:42.124Z")
    },
    {
        content: 'content 7',
        userId: '123',
        targetUserId: '345',
        timestamp: ISODate("2023-11-06T20:03:42.124Z")
    }
];

const result = input.reduce((groups, curr, index, arr) => {
  // if we are just getting started or userId is different
  // than previous one
  if(index === 0 || curr.userId !== arr[index - 1].userId) {
    // create new group and add current to it in one line
    const g = [curr];
    // add new group to the groups array
    groups.push(g);
  } else {
    // we are on the same user group so we should just add our
    // message to last group
    groups[groups.length - 1].push(curr);
  }

  // remember to return groups again
  return groups;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```